# How to find a specific array in an object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my contents of a document in the MongoDB. It has an object `timestamps`
and a lot of arrays.

```
"timestamps" : {
    "1200" : [ 
        "390.288", 
        "390.818", 
        "So"
    ],
    "1175" : [ 
        "381.778", 
        "382.248", 
        "so"
    ],
    "1183" : [ 
        "383.668", 
        "383.928", 
        "a"
    ],
    "1144" : [ 
        "372.588", 
        "372.718", 
        "up"
    ],
    "1162" : [ 
        "377.638", 
        "377.928", 
        "rial"
    ],
    "1218" : [ 
        "395.798", 
        "395.868", 
        "me"
    ],
    "1145" : [ 
        "372.718", 
        "373.188", 
        "So"
    ]
```

}

How can I find the array element with the key "1162"?

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$project":{"timestamps":{"$objectToArray":"$timestamps"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$timestamps"},
  {"$match":{ "k" : "1162" }  }
]) // mongoDB version 3.6

Comment: @AhmedKesha, thank you. But this is what worked for me `db.collection.find({"timestamps":{"$exists":true}},{"timestamps.0":1,"_id":0})`.  This returns this                                                            
 `{
    "timestamps" : {
        "0" : [ 
            "0.000", 
            "0.100", 
            "Hey"
        ]
    }
}`